# Delete "Closed as not constructive" with 10 Down Votes?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, closed-questions, vote-to-close

How about deleting the questions which are not welcome to be entertained?

Few things:

1. Some questions are closed as not constructive even when it has many upvotes - which means, people like them.
2. Some questions are closed as not constructive and also has down votes - which means, people do not like them.

In either case, "Closing a question" (not protected - closed) - indirectly means - You're not allowed to answer because this question is not welcome here.

Considering that we want to keep users happy, we may rule out deleting it completely for point 1 but, "*I do not see*" any apparent reason to keep questions, like those mentioned in point 2.

My point is, how about implementing a feature of 'deleting' the posts with 10 downvotes instead of keeping them?

It's like recruiting an employee to show company strength (be there on Google), irrespective of his productivity (of it being closed).

Thoughts?

Comment: What is wrong with the current system? What is the actual problem you're solving here?

Comment: well, I came across my own question on Google , which was marked as non-constructive, limiting me to few answers to choose from. There are even questions which I came across in past, which were closed as not constructive, no answers... but, it was still there...

Comment: Automatic deletion for old questions without any other content and a negative score already exists. For closed questions with answers though, the answers might still be of value. I don't really see a need to target those with deletion. Or at least not to a point where I think we need far more users participating in their deletion.

Comment: I wonder if this post is related here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400159

Comment: +1 for your analysis and marking a down-vote on it. AGAIN! I am sure, you did it!... :P

But, Yes................ I googled for Java EE suggestion and there it was! Closed as non constructive. I marked for deletion. I still there !!! Thought about asking u to implement an automated system...

Comment: You are sure *I* did it? Ok; it's your assumption to make. But at least it does seem your actual motivation is revealed, here. Nothing *at all wrong* with that motivation, but... (insert assumption here)

Comment: Whats up with _but... (insert assumption here)_ remark??? No use getting Personal here Mr. Andrew Barber, your dry reply wasn't appreciated, a simple **No** was good? It was not my actual motivation (which was your assumption) but, also a suggestion... I have been doing reviews (performing towards civic duty) and _giving back_ to Stack community, we are even. My motivation was to see if this can be made better, irrespective of my question. Next time, no dry comment please.

Comment: After you posted it here, I have been getting constant downvotes. Is this a way to bully, @AndrewBarber ? How about a justification on repeated downvotes?

Comment: @KarmicDice Votes are anonymous by design. Comments on downvotes have been proposed here many times before and have been rejected each and every time. There is no bullying going on here. The link caused your question to get extra attention. And users voted on that question as they saw fit. That's all.

Comment: Ofc this is bullying @Bart . People slog to 'earn' the reputation! Give answers based on research, help one another and try to deliver best... SHARE WITHOUT HESITATION!!! Such reputation is earned in a hard way! And just because one question was asked in a 'wrong' way, positive reputation is being affected! This is discouraging, VERY discouraging. Look at the answers I have posted on Stackoverflow, tried to give best to community and earned repos... and this is treatment you give, saying 'thats all' and STILL it is NOT deleted!

Comment: Again, my point of this Thread was not that question.

Answer (score 9):

Deletion is a very high privilege, (10K), *Instant* deletion is an even **higher** privilege (20K).

It only takes 3 privileged people to delete.

If your example question is that bad, it will be deleted by 3 20K users soon enough. What you're proposing is practically giving 125 reputation users partial deletion privilege.

While they already have some (6 spam/offensive flags), I don't feel that it's necessary in this case.

#### In short

No, don't implement this please.

Comment: How about raising the margin from 5 downvotes + marked non-constructive TO 10 downvites + marked non-constructive?

Comment: This will make moderator's life easier?

Comment: @KarmicDice: Again, *why?*, the post will be deleted much before that by 3 privileged users. It's not necessary in my opinion. It has nothing to do with moderators, they don't handle this stuff anyway (unless someone flags). 3 20K reputation users are fully capable of handling it.

Comment: @KarmicDice [Automatic deletion of old questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) already exists and is far harder to abuse than any low threshold low rep deletion process. People abused the spam flags as low threshold deletion when they were visible to users. Monitoring and spotting abuse of a downvote based system would be hard.

Comment: ` Monitoring and spotting abuse of a downvote based system would be hard.` Hmmmm, I would but that...

Comment: but, I think we also have a reverse upvote system already... cant we implement reverse downvote system? I mean, just a suggestion... Pragmatically, it is challenging... agreed.

Comment: @KarmicDice: Automatic vote reversal is active regardless of the vote's direction (up/down). But that's not what he meant.

Comment: @Bart: "Serial voting reversed"

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Yeah, as you say, already exists

Comment: Okay... Check my comment on the question.. as reply to Andrew Barber

Answer (score 5):

Automatic deletion of anything should never happen on anything but old questions, it should only be done by a human who can analyze the impact of removing a question, and then only with someone who has moderator-level privileges.

Don't forget that a normal (less than 10K) user cannot see his/her own deleted questions in their question list (although they can be found in the "deleted recent questions" if the question was asked recently), so by deleting instantly once a specific reputation threshold is reached, you are not giving the OP a real chance to fix it as some questions on active sites (like Stack Overflow) can hit number very quickly.  In fairness it is not likely that the OP will be able to edit enough to salvage the question in most cases, but you still need to give them an opportunity.

Comment: *Instant deletion of anything should never happen automatically on anything but very old questions*, that makes it a bit not "instant" don't you think? :D

Comment: I added the `very old questions` part to clarify the fact that automatic deletion does happen on old questions in specific circumstances.  But the wording could stand some improvement

Comment: @MadaraUchiha that works, thanks, I was just making the same edit